# How to get block in custom phtml with selected array of values

Tags: magento2.4.1

I am trying to get the same block on two custom phtml files,

1. abc.phtml here i need selected data from array,
2. xyz.phtml here i need all data from array, how to achieve this?

My format:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location")->setTemplate("Amasty_Storelocator::center.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Update your question with proper eg. what you want to achieve

Comment: @RakeshVarma I am using a third-party extension, i need the block into my two separate custom phtml file, any ref thanks.

Comment: if you want to use that block in your phtml file then you can add that block in layout file where you define your template file.

Comment: My template under : app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Theme\templates\location_link.phtml, how to include template file layout xml file?

Comment: how loation_link.phtml will render? or other word on which page or section it will render?

Comment: Home page below header : https://codeshare.io/5NEYQo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120873/discussion-between-zus-and-rakesh-varma).

Comment: I have added code in my answer which work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can call phtml inside phtml like this.

```
<referenceBlock name="header.panel">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mycustom.block" template="Magento_Theme::location_link.phtml" after="-" >
        <block class="Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location" name="custom.location.block" template="Amasty_Storelocator::center.phtml"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

and inside **location_link.phtml** file add below code

```
<?= $this->getChildHtml('custom.location.block');?>
```

as discussed in chat this code is worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can call in both phtml files same block

For ex your block class is

```
<?php
namespace Vandor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Main extends Template
{
    public function getMyCustomMethod()
    {
        return '<p>CustomMethod</p>';
    }
}
```

in your phtml file

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vandor\Module\Block\Main');
echo $blockObj->getMyCustomMethod();
?>
```

upvote if helps

Comment: Blocks should be created via layouts, not in templates...

Comment: you can achieve everything by this method also

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to block

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Amasty\Storelocator\Block\Location")->setCustomData($array)->setTemplate("Amasty_Storelocator::center.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

and get in phtml

```
<?php $retriveArray = $block->getCustomData(); ?>
```